# LD_LIBRARY_PATH contains the traditional /lib directory, but not the multiarch directory /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, dpkg

I unfortunately tried to install teamviewer in ubuntu 16.04 but failed. I tried to remove most of the packages which required a dependency, using this command:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq liblzma5:i386 libc6-dbg:amd64 libpam-systemd:amd64 libgcrypt20:i386  libc6-i386 libpcre3:i386 libasound2:i386 libgpg-error0:i386 libselinux1:i386 libc6-dev:amd64 libgcc1:i386
```

but I got stuck here.

```
sayantan@sayantan-labPC:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
[sudo] password for sayantan: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libc6 libpam-systemd libsystemd0 systemd
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc systemd-ui systemd-container
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc6 libpam-systemd libsystemd0 systemd
4 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 127 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/6,690 kB of archives.
After this operation, 54.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 321169 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.23-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...

LD_LIBRARY_PATH contains the traditional /lib directory,
but not the multiarch directory /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu.
It is not safe to upgrade the C library in this situation;
please remove the /lib/directory from LD_LIBRARY_PATH and
try again.

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.23-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.23-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
sayantan@sayantan-labPC:~$
```

I checked the current LD_CONFIG_PATH, but still it doesn't help:

```
sayantan@sayantan-labPC:~$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
sayantan@sayantan-labPC:~$
```

I even tried to force overwrite the package, but still it resulted in the same result.

```
sayantan@sayantan-labPC:~$ sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.23-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 321169 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.23-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...

LD_LIBRARY_PATH contains the traditional /lib directory,
but not the multiarch directory /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu.
It is not safe to upgrade the C library in this situation;
please remove the /lib/directory from LD_LIBRARY_PATH and
try again.

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.23-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb (--install):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.23-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
sayantan@sayantan-labPC:~$
```

please help resolve the problem.

Comment: Where and why are you setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? it's empty by default, and its use is largely deprecated AFAIK

Comment: It was initially `/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64`, but for that session i changed it to what it wanted. I even tried the same after making the variable empty. The same output came up.